# How do I enable Extra Visual Effects using an Intel graphics controller?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, intel-graphics, proprietary

I'm using an office desktop computer with Ubuntu 10.04 installed. I know the Intel graphics controller should be able to pull off the simple desktop effects made available by Compiz, but I can't convince Ubuntu to try. When I try to enable Extra Effects it pops up the "Hardware Drivers" dialog and concludes after a while "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system", with the list below empty.

Note, I used to have nVidia drivers installed. I moved the SSD from my old computer to this new one.

I would like to know what I must learn in order to enable Extra Effects on Ubuntu using  Intel graphics controller

**My xorg.conf:** (it's the default output from `$ Xorg -configure`)

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: : integer, : float, : "True"/"False",
        ### : "String", : " Hz/kHz/MHz"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "DRI"                   # []
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # 
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # 
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # []
        #Option     "Tiling"                # []
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # []
        #Option     "Shadow"                # []
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # []
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # []
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # []
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # []
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # []
        #Option     "RelaxedFencing"        # []
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    VendorName  "Intel Corporation"
    BoardName   "Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**`$ glxinfo` output:**

```
name of display: :0.0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
3 GLXFBConfigs:
   visual  x  bf lv rg d st colorbuffer ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
 id dep cl sp sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Segmentation fault
```

**`$ uname -a` output:**

```
$ uname -a
Linux tes-ubuntu-w350 3.0.0-19-generic #33~lucid1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 20 13:55:
08 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please comment if there is more relevant information I can provide

---

### What I have done

Installed the newest available kernel from apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.0.0-19-generic linux-headers-3.0.0-19-gener
ic
```

Added these to my sources

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/intel-driver/ubuntu lucid main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/intel-driver/ubuntu lucid main
```

And run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check this link to read up on the error: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8849106&postcount=11

Solution (provided in above link):

```
    sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Comment: Wow, worked like a charm! :D