# Falling back to unity-2D after an update

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, unity-2d, nvidia-optimus

I have a laptop with nvidia optimus technology and I had installed bumblebee (running ubuntu 12.04 64bit).

After an update ubuntu-2d is loaded (I verified that with `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` printing ubuntu-2d) even if "ubuntu" is selected at the login screen.

What can I do to restore unity-3D?

Comment: Possibly related to a recent update - http://askubuntu.com/questions/262320/after-ubuntu-12-04-lts-update-only-unity-2d-bug?rq=1

Comment: @Heather: Thank you! The question you've posted contained a link to the solution

Comment: Glad you found a solution! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after looking the question Heather posted as a comment.
Source of solution is [here](https://theiszm.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/glx-missing-on-display/)
These are the steps that have to be done:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel  libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
```

After these, I've restarted my system and unity-3D is loaded.