# Cannot get Asus laptop to correctly wake up from Suspend mode

Tags: 12.04, suspend, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have Asus X53S laptop running Ubuntu 12.04.
On my previous 12.04 installation, suspend was working.
Now, after waking up from suspend mode, all I got, was a blank screen.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. The script mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53372/suspend-hibernate-doesnt-work-on-an-asus-laptop)
2. Adding `acpi_osi=Linux` at `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`
3. Adding `quiet splash nolapic` at `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`
4. After these, I ran `sudo update-grub`
5. Also, disabled, requesting password after wake up

**Results:**

6. Now, the screen after wake up isn't blank, but it's the last screen that was displayed before the suspend (probably).
7. Moving the mouse, shows nothing - which is, the display is dead.

**Some progress:**

8. Switching to tty1 (`Ctrl + Alt + F1`) got me at a terminal with a working screen. From which I could use `sudo lightdm restart`, which did nothing.
9. After that, I typed `who` and saw that my user was connected to tty7, so I changed to it, and voila, I have now access to my session, as it was before the suspend.

**But with problems:**

10. Probably the graphics are messed up. The border of the right click dialog is a thick white one (about 4mm).
11. My wallpaper doesn't show up, and instead I get this: [image: wallpaper error and border of terminal window]

*Look the wallpaper, and also, the border of the terminal window.*

---

**On a sidenote,** my laptop has a Nvidia GTX520M GPU (with the "great" optimus technology).
**Some related info:**

1. Running Additional Drivers program, I see that the version 331 of Nvidia Driver is activated and currently in use
2. I remember that at my previous installation I had installed BumbleBee.

Should I try deactivating the proprietary driver, removing it, and then installing BumbleBee?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by doing the following:

1. Opened Additional Drivers app, and Deactivated the driver in use
2. Rebooted (something was wrong with the cursor, as it was going *way* past the screen on the right
3. Ran all the commands from *well* my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282145/falling-back-to-unity-2d-after-an-update) regarding a problem with the same laptop.

Now, it wakes up from suspend successfully! :)

Comment: Mark as answered. :D

Comment: @DušanMilosevic: I can mark it as answer after 22h :( Will do that tomorrow :)